# Updated ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) MVC5 Project Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, rider, clean-architecture, .net-4.8

The project that visual studio 2019 creates for an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) MVC5 comes with Bootstrap 3.x and many other outdated components. Not to mention unneeded things like modernizr.

If you update Bootstrap, you know need to modify the ScriptBundle in BundleConfig to get the application to start, and then modify the CSS to get the premade web pages to render properly.

Also, the folder structure is not the best.

Is there a project template out there that has all essential components updated, and a clean-up NuGet and folder structure?

I tried using Rider but they do not have a built-in template.

I went t the .Net Foundation GitHub and did not find any: https://github.com/dotnet?q=.NET+framework&type=&language=c%23&sort=

I also search GitHubub and did not see any: https://github.com/search?q=ASP.NET+Web+Application+%28.NET+Framework%29+project+template

I am looking for a project template that has the basic structure to create a Clean Architecture **in .NET Framework and not .NET Core**

I know it's legacy, but unfortunately, I need it for a university class (University courses take a while to get updated, and in this case, they claim that there are sufficient companies out there using ASP.NET MVC 5 to Merrit them teaching it) But yes, No one should be using this to start a new project they intend to put into a real-life production scenario.

Thank you

Comment: For legacy technologies, the common case is to help yourself (as most people has already moved away a long time ago).

Comment: LOL, yes @LexLi , I know; we can't support everything forever.